# Crystal Reports in ASP.NET 2.0 app - report changes not showing

Tags: asp.net, iis, crystal-reports, asp.net-2.0

I'm developing an ASP.NET 2.0 application that includes Crystal Reports (version 10, included with VS 2005).  Originally, the reports were working properly, both when run from my machine using the ASP.NET development web server, and also when deployed to an IIS server.

I made some changes to the reports and re-deployed the app to the IIS server, but the report changes are not showing up when I run the application (although they are showing up when serving the app locally on my machine).  Is it possible the IIS server is caching older copies of the rpt files and  not flushing them properly?  I suggested this possibility to the guy managing the server, but he said he re-started the app pool and it didn't make a difference.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The report source object has a cache duration(in seconds) property. I think it is set to 60 seconds by default. You can either shorten this and then run the report again or alternatively you can turn it off by another property "enableCacheing". I have had mixed results with turning cacheing off so I usually just use the aspx page to set the property on the report source and lower it to 1 second to refresh the report, and then raise it back up once the cache has cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that the new one didn't get renamed somewhere in the process and the code is still referring to the old one.

What happens if you temporarily remove the RPT file on the web server? If you don't get an error, it's loading the report from someplace else.

Are there subreports involved?