# Asp.net Crystal Reports changes to child reports not showing in vs2017 debug/release mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017, crystal-reports-2013

Similar to the user in my first link, I've inherited an ASP.NET web application which displays reports using Crystal Reports. I was asked to edit some of the reports and make some new ones but my subreport changes are not being displayed when the report is called with the site running in the IDE.  I realize from what I've read that the .rpt files are rolled into the DLL but how are the parent report changes working and the subreports changes not?

The report(s) I'm working on is/are a parent report that outputs information and then has 5 embedded sub reports (child?) that output the rest.  (All of the report is shown in PDF format.)

I had originally not been able to see changes to either the parent or children reports but yesterday I discovered (4th day working on this problem) that when I changed the Solution Configurations dropdown from Debug to Release my changes to the PARENT report ARE correctly showing in the running site IDE.  However, no matter what I change for the child reports the code that is running is the code that I was originally given/compiled and does not contain any of my subreport .rpt changes.  The running file(s) has/have to be on my computer somewhere, I brought all the code here from nothing and it builds and runs in my IDE.

Things I've done/checked:

Both the child and parent report .rpts that I am editing reside in the same directory.  They are in solution\subproject\Reports.  I have verified changes to the files modified immediately after making a change.

I tried Starting/Stopping the IDE

I tried Starting/Stopping the computer

I tried Publishing the project after Rebuild.  Publishes with no errors but the subreport changes do not show up.

I tried right clicking the individual .rpt file and choosing 'Publish ReportName.rpt'.  Gave errors stating that the bin/Release/PublishOutput Web Site does not exist.

In the properties pane:
The Build Action for all the .rpt files is set to 'Content'.

I changed the Copy to Output Directory property to 'Copy Always'.

As soon as I start the site via the IDE the changed files are copied to:
solution\subproject\bin\Reports\

Now that I have the Solution Configurations dropdown set to Release, the corresponding Build/Configuration Manager is set to Release.  The Platform is Any CPU and all Build checkboxes are checked.  (None of the Deploy checkboxes are checked.)

I have not tried 'Deleting ASP.net temp files'.

My research includes this:
[Crystal Report Not Showing Changes to Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343024/crystal-report-not-showing-changes-to-report)

Then this:
[Crystal Reports in ASP.NET 2.0 app - report changes not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337713/crystal-reports-in-asp-net-2-0-app-report-changes-not-showing)

Also saw something on an SAP site but lost the link...

Comment: Did you update the subreports in the main report or just the subreport files separately. If you did update separately you need to open the main report and right-click the subreport and choose `Re-import Subreport`

Comment: Franck:  Thank you sooo much.  I just found that out myself and it worked and you have confirmed it.  I don't know how to mark your comment as the answer so I will add the answer and credit you.

Comment: You can't mark as an answer a comment. I didn't make an answer as my comment was mostly a question / clarification and an answer would have been highly speculative.

Answer (score 0):

As Franck indicates above:

'Did you update the subreports in the main report or just the subreport files separately. If you did update separately you need to open the main report and right-click the subreport and choose Re-import Subreport.'

Editing the subreport, Re-importing and rebuilding the site allowed my changes to be seen while running the IDE!  Thank you so much!